# How can I implement Common Class for Current User to retrieve its data from Firebase whenever I needed, without calling same method again and again

Tags: java, android

[This my Registration Activity in that I have to store Data of current User in Common Class, So whenever I needed I can directly call it.  For Example: if I have to set Text. so set Text.(Common . current User. get Username)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SsZbu.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to make a singleton class and access it anywhere you want.

Singleton class Like:

```
   public class singleTonExample {
      String editValue;
      private static final singleTonExample ourInstance = new singleTonExample();
   public static singleTonExample getInstance() {
      return ourInstance;
   }
   private singleTonExample() { }
   public void setText(String editValue) {
      this.editValue = editValue;
   }
   public String getText() {
      return editValue;
   }
}
```

and you call it activity as:

```
singleTonExample singletonexample = com.example.singleTonExample.getInstance();
    singletonexample.setText(editValue);
```

Comment: I have to save current Users data and After that I have to call in other Activities without calling database reference.

Comment: Yes, singleton work in your idea, It's also suggested by official Android site

Comment: A big Thank You, It Worked For me.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use static

```
public class CommonData {
    public static String userName;
    public static ..... //whatever you want

}
```

to retrive the data just call

```
CommonData.userName;
CommonData......
```